# Is it possible to get the results of Facebook's URL scraper via an API endpoint?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have tried to look into their documentation, but haven't found anything that would help me answer my question. I am trying to get the image and the description of a URL from Facebook's Scraper. I see they have a nice resource that displays this as this: `https://graph.facebook.com/728207680562365` but I wanted this to be more dynamic, so as to speak, making a GET request to Graph API with my URL would return the response. Does anyone have an idea if this is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closest thing you'll get to is Facebook's URL node: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/url.

By default the `og_object` returns the following fields:

- id
- url
- type
- title
- description
- updated_time

This doesn't sum up all the fields however. You can get other specific fields like so:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/?id=<<yoururl>>&fields=og_object.fields(image)&access_token=<<yourtoken>>
```

Using a real URL: (substitute an access token)

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/?id=http://sauce-dev.myshopify.com/products/flower-print-jeans&fields=og_object.fields(image)&access_token=<<yourtoken>>
```

Comment: Chris, my friend, what a small world it is. Well, I've looked at that, gives me some interesting data, but won't tell me anything w.r.t the image. I have had to develop my own fetcher uses meta tags and og:image. Got images of about 2500/2600. Not bad, but if Facebook API has a workaround as I wished, it would be way more faster.

Comment: Small world indeed! Just updated my answer to help you on that.

Comment: Can you do a sample so I can click the link and see it working. I usually use http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://redis.io/ to get other details, but I can't see the image after appending your query params. I get this error: {
"error": {
"message": "(#100) Unknown fields: og_object.",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 100
}
}

Comment: Updated example with real URL. Make sure you're using v2.1 by the way.

Comment: Perfect, works. So I was just using their public API which doesn't require a token, but looks like I'll have to get my token and use it well. Also, there are some rate limiting for using my token to access their API, isn't it? I am processing huge amounts of data. Might get throttled or something?

Comment: Assume there's no rate limits. Unless you're a huge huge company, you won't be hitting them any time soon.

Comment: Good point, by the way, my access token expires from the Graph API explorer every hour, how do I automate this process to get a new one or better, get a long lived token?

Comment: You can extend it to ~60 days https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: I tried, but the access token that I get from there is like 16 bits and it won't work when I put it in the URL. Any clue how you'd do it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61320/discussion-between-chris-houghton-and-ali-gajani).

Comment: And how to get likes/shares count using this method?

Comment: `share_count` and `comment_count` are sent back in the response. Note that this doesn't offer as much info as FQL does.