# Facebook GraphAPI and FQL API return different value for same URL

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I trying to migrate my facebook app from FQL API (1.0) to GraphAPI (2.3) and i encounter some problems.

Main goal of my facebook application is fetching current count of likes, shares and comments for specified links (article url). (I think, something similar to [How to get facebook share, like, comment count for a url with graph api only (in a non-deprecated way)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940403/how-to-get-facebook-share-like-comment-count-for-a-url-with-graph-api-only-in))

In (old) FQL API i could get this information by executing SELECT ... FROM link_stat table. ex.:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxx|yyyyyyyya&q=SELECT%20click_count%2Ccomment_count%2Ccommentsbox_count%2Clike_count%2Cshare_count%2Ctotal_count%2Cnormalized_url%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url%20IN%20%28"http%3A//sport.wp.pl/kat%2C1715%2Ctitle%2CSwiat-pokochal-polskiego-sportowca-Mimo-ze-ledwo-dukal-po-angielsku%2Cwid%2C17449498%2Cwiadomosc.html"%29
```

which return information in JSON, ex.:

```
{
 "data": [
  {
   "like_count": 21, 
   "comment_count": 0, 
   "click_count": 0, 
   "commentsbox_count": 0, 
   "total_count": 29, 
   "share_count": 8, 
   "normalized_url": "http://sport.wp.pl/kat,1715,title,Swiat-pokochal-polskiego-sportowca-Mimo-ze-ledwo-dukal-po-angielsku,wid,17449498,wiadomosc.html"
  }
 ]
}
```

In new GraphAPI (2.3) theoretically this information is available via:

URL and /{object-id}/likes edges:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/url
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/object/likes

Which return value. ex.:

```
{
 "share": {
  "comment_count": 0, 
  "share_count": 42
 }, 
 "og_object": {
  "url": "http://sport.wp.pl/kat,1715,title,Swiat-pokochal-polskiego-sportowca-Mimo-ze-ledwo-dukal-po-angielsku,wid,17449498,wiadomosc.html", 
  "description": "Kibice wstrzymali oddech, dos\u0142ownie. W sali s\u0142ycha\u0107 by\u0142o tykaj\u0105c\u0105 wskaz\u00f3wk\u0119 zegara zawieszonego na \u015bcianie. Przy stole sta\u0142 Bogdan Wo\u0142kowski, nieruchomo patrzy\u0142 na \u015brodek, gdzie znajdowa\u0142a si\u0119 wysoka piramida z\u0142o\u017cona z kilku poziom\u00f3w bil i tr\u00f3jk\u0105t\u00f3w. Na jej szczycie sta\u0142 cz\u0142owiek. Mija\u0142y kolejne sekundy, napi\u0119cie ros\u0142o. Nagle \"Wizard\" wzi\u0105\u0142 kij do r\u0119ki, przymierzy\u0142, hukn\u0105\u0142 w bil\u0119, ta uderzy\u0142a w piramid\u0119 i...", 
  "type": "article", 
  "title": "\u015awiat pokocha\u0142 polskiego sportowca. Mimo \u017ce ledwo duka\u0142 po angielsku", 
  "updated_time": "2015-04-14T19:46:03+0000", 
  "id": "1055320127830544"
 }, 
 "id": "http://sport.wp.pl/kat,1715,title,Swiat-pokochal-polskiego-sportowca-Mimo-ze-ledwo-dukal-po-angielsku,wid,17449498,wiadomosc.html"
}
```

and

```
{
 "1055320127830544": {
  "data": [], 
  "summary": {
   "total_count": 0
  }
 }
}
```

Unfortunately this values isn't consistent with results from FQL API .

So, my question is:
What mean each value in response, and why it is not consistent with FQL?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a known issue with the API. You can follow [this post](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/640941529356484/) for updates.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699270/how-to-get-share-counts-using-graph-api/5700882#5700882) has a good explanation of how to get share counts.

Also what I have noticed is that for API version 2.1 and above, `share_count` in the response contains the total number of shares including the link shared directly on the Timeline by the user. For version 2.0, I think `shares` in the response excludes this.